# ProvideToolBoxControl Could not be found

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Hi there I am working with WPF and I created several custom control in WPF library I want to add them all to same tab group in toolbox, I googled it most of the solutions suggested the ProvideToolBoxControl attribute but I couldn't find the assembly for this attribute, does any one knows how to import assembly for mentioned attribute?

```
[ProvideToolBoxControl("MyControls", false)]
public class UETextBox : TextBox
{
    static UETextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UETextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(UETextBox)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a VSIX project to manage your several custom controls. I created a ToolBox like the picture shown.

[image]

Here is my step (**Open the Visual Studio > click New Project >choose WPF Toolbox Control to name your ToolBox> Click the Solution Explorer > Add > New Item >  Visual C# > Extensibility >WPF Toolbox Control** ).  Then in the solution, you could create the control UIs.  For more details, you could refer to this document([Create a WPF Toolbox Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-a-wpf-toolbox-control?view=vs-2019)).